# Cmake error: Invalid escape sequence \U

Tags: path, cmake

While running my OpenCL code in VC++ 10 by using CMake I am getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (set): Syntax error in cmake code at
C:/Users/Shreedhar/Desktop/testCL/CMakeLists.txt:6

when parsing string
C:\Users\Shreedhar\Desktop\test_CL\CMakeLists
Invalid escape sequence \U
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use forward slashes `/` in your paths

```
C:/Users/Shreedhar/Desktop/test_CL/CMakeLists
```

Comment: Or escape the backslashes: `C:\\Users\\Shreedhar\\Desktop\\test_CL\\CMakeLists`

Comment: In a lot of cases you could also use quotes. Most of the time I just use slashes instead of backslashes and avoid this.

Comment: Really confused where to change the path.I'm using `camke gui` on `windows ` it just get the path by selecting,not by typing.

Comment: In Windows, one should be able to give paths to CMake using backslashes. What would fix this is if the project defined a variable properly with type PATH and assigned the path there. If CMake knows it has a path, it can do backslash conversion automatically.

Answer (score 18):

If you are reading user input like environment variables then you'll need to do this by character replacement feature of string method.

```
string(REPLACE "\\" "/" outputVar ${_inputVar})
```

Comment: Why it no to do cmake automaticaly?

Comment: How does one do this when the value is a parameter... for example: `MACRO(foobar input) string(REPLACE "\\" "/" output ${input}) ENDMACRO()` doesn't work. It gives the parse error. I know we can do it at the calling point, but that is often inefficient

Answer (score 3):

For those who receive this error under Windows:

> CMake Error at
>   C:/Dev/cmake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:903 (list):
>   Syntax error in cmake code at
>
> ```
> C:/Dev/cmake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:903
> ```
>
> when parsing string
>
> ```
> C:\Dev\mongodb\src\boost/lib${_arch_suffix}-msvc-15.0
> ```
>
> Invalid character escape '\D'. Call Stack (most recent call first): 
>   C:/Dev/cmake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1379
>   (_Boost_UPDATE_WINDOWS_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_WITH_PREBUILT_PATHS)
>   src/bsoncxx/CMakeLists.txt:100 (find_package)

Don't set the BOOST_ROOT environment variable to a backslash-ended value.

Comment: I meet the same error,however the solution doesn't fix it.