# CMake error: ItkVtkGlue

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017, vtk, itk

I built `VTK-8.0.0` (using `msvc2017_64`) and `ITK-4.12.0` (using `msvc2017_64`). During the ITK-build as below:

---

1) building VTK (`CMake3.9.0`)

2) building ITK (CMake3.9.0): `Module_ITKVtkGlue` + `VTK_DIR this path C:\VTK\8.0.0\build\msvc2017_64`

3) Compiling VTK using msvc2017 (in Release mode)

4) Create a new environment variable `VTK_DIR` with the value `C:\VTK\8.0.0\build\msvc2017_64`

5) Add to the path: `%VTK_DIR%\bin\Release`

6)  Compiling ITK using msvc2017 (in Release mode)

7) Creating a new environment variable `ITK_DIR` with the value `C:\ITK\4.12.0\build\msvc2017_64`

8) Add to the path: `%ITK_DIR%\bin\Release`

---

And now, I only want to build and compile a very simple project from the link below:
https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/IO/ImageToVTKImageFilter

however, I can't configure the project getting the error below in CMake:

```
***************************************************************

CMake Error at C:/ITK/4.12.0/build/msvc2017_64/lib/cmake/ITK-4.12/Modules/ITKVtkGlue.cmake:14 (set):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    C:/ITK/4.12.0/build/msvc2017_64/lib/cmake/ITK-4.12/Modules/ITKVtkGlue.cmake:14

  when parsing string

    C:\VTK\8.0.0\build\msvc2017_64

  Invalid escape sequence \V
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/ITK/4.12.0/src/CMake/ITKModuleAPI.cmake:54 (include)
  C:/ITK/4.12.0/src/CMake/ITKModuleAPI.cmake:26 (itk_module_load)
  C:/ITK/4.12.0/src/CMake/ITKModuleAPI.cmake:84 (_itk_module_config_recurse)
  C:/ITK/4.12.0/build/msvc2017_64/ITKConfig.cmake:74 (itk_module_config)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/new_dev/tests/ImageToVTKImageFilter/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
***************************************************************
```

To solve this problem, at first, I tried to add an Entry with `ItkVtkGlue` path but the same error was achieved. Then, I created `ItkVtkGlue.lib` individually and added added a new environment variable `ItkVtkGlue_DIR` with the value `C:\ItkVtkGlue\build\Release` and also added to the path and again creating an Entry for `ItkVtkGlue`, but I got the same error.

I would appreciate any help...
Deeply looking forward to your advice ...

Comment: `Create a new environment variable VTK_DIR with the value 'C:\VTK\8.0.0\build\msvc2017_64'` - When set path variables for CMake, do not use backslash in them, use forward slash instead: `C:/VTK/8.0.0/build/msvc2017_64`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cmake error: Invalid escape sequence \U](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737370/cmake-error-invalid-escape-sequence-u)

Comment: First of all, thanks, I did it, again the same error. please have a look at https://ibb.co/cZNr9k                                                                                            *** just a kind reminder, when building an individual itk or vtk project, it goes well, but in the case of itk+vtk, I got such an error...

Comment: What is content of the line error log refers to (`/ITK/4.12.0/build/msvc2017_64/lib/cmake/ITK-4.12/Modules/ITKVtkGlue.cmake:14`)?

Comment: Could you please have a look at: https://ufile.io/vh05b   and https://ufile.io/ss2qb

Comment: `CMakeCache.txt` and output are not interesting (at least, at now). I asked about the particular line in the file which exists only on your PC.

Comment: sorry, I uploaded the wrong file, you can find CMakeError here: https://ufile.io/0ycrr

Comment: File `/ITK/4.12.0/build/msvc2017_64/lib/cmake/ITK-4.12/Modules/IT‌​KVtkGlue.cmake` is not an error log. This is a normal file, but its content depends on your machine (more precise, it depends on installation of VTK).

Comment: So sorry Tsyvarev, I just got what you meant... I'll come back in a minute...

Comment: You were right, the problem was about the VTK address in the IKVtkGlue.cmake. In fact, the VTK_DIR was set to "C:\VTK\8.0.0\build\msvc2017_64". II changed to set(VTK_DIR "C:/VTK/8.0.0/build/msvc2017_64") and it works now. Thanks Tsyvarev for your guides.

Comment: You can simplify your life by building VTK and ITK as static libraries, by setting BUILD_SHARED_LIBS to OFF. And I think it is OFF by default. Then there is no need to fiddle with environment variables or adding anything to PATH.

Comment: If you used cmake-gui's built-in path browser, it would have written the path with forward slashes into your edit field (and later into the file). Even if you copy-paste the path with backslashes, CMake offers auto-completed path with forwards slashes. I hope this will make your life easier in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue went back to the `VTK_DIR` which was defined by "\". First, I tried to replace all "\" in my environment variable `VTK_DIR` with "/" but it resulted in the same error. Then I defined VTK_DIR as an Entry in CMake and a path with "/" was dedicated, again the same error. In fact the problem was due to the `ITKVtkGlue.cmake`. The `VTK_DIR` was set by "\" and I manually replaced them by "/", and now `ITK+VTK` goes well...