# Unable to install eigen in clion

Tags: cmake, eigen

I am new to programing and am using Clion to code. I have tried configuring the eigen library in C make but I am unable to do so.

My C make file is as follows :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(Laser_ablation_nanoparticles)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

set(EIGEN_DIR "C:\Users\Vishal\Documents\Academic documents\MSc\Manchester\dissertation\Eigen\eigen-3.4.0\eigen-3.4.0\Eigen")
if(NOT EXISTS ${EIGEN_DIR})
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Please check that the set Eigen directory is valid!")
endif()

include_directories(${EIGEN_DIR})

add_executable(Laser_ablation_nanoparticles main.cpp)
```

My resposnse is :

"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.1.5\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.1.5/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" -G Ninja -S C:\Users\Vishal\CLionProjects\Laser_ablation_nanoparticles -B C:\Users\Vishal\CLionProjects\Laser_ablation_nanoparticles\cmake-build-debug
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (set):
Syntax error in cmake code at

```
C:/Users/Vishal/CLionProjects/Laser_ablation_nanoparticles/CMakeLists.txt:6
```

when parsing string

```
C:\Users\Vishal\Documents\Academic documents\MSc\Manchester\dissertation\Eigen\eigen-3.4.0\eigen-3.4.0\Eigen
```

Invalid character escape '\U'.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Vishal/CLionProjects/Laser_ablation_nanoparticles/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

[Failed to reload]

I have eigen dense at :
C:\xxx\dissertation\Eigen\eigen-3.4.0\eigen-3.4.0\Eigen

Comment: Don't use backslash characters. Use forward slashes in your path. Also, I'm pretty sure the `EIGEN_DIR` should be set to the `eigen-3.4.0` directory, not the `Eigen` directory within

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cmake error: Invalid escape sequence \U](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737370/cmake-error-invalid-escape-sequence-u)

Comment: The backward slaches solved it , Thank you